# Passing element ID from HTML to TypeScript

Tags: html, typescript

I have the following form where each option has an ID. I would like to read each ID into TypeScript. How do I approach such a scenario?

**HTML file**

```
  <div class="form-group" style="width: 350px">
      <label for="form_periodicity"><b>Periodicity</b></label><br>
      <select class="form-control" id="periodicity" 
       style="width: 222px">
        <option id="opt_eod">EOD</option>
        <option id="opt_daily">Daily</option>
        <option id="opt_weekly">Weekly</option>
        <option id="opt_monthly">Monthly</option>
        <option id="opt_strict_run">Strict run</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

I would like to store the id's in a string variable in TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all of the options for a select element using `getElementByTagName`. You can loop over those and get all of their ids:

```
const selectElement = <HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementById('periodicity');
const optionElements = selectElement.getElementsByTagName('option');
const ids = [];

for (let i = 0; i < optionElements.length; i++) {
    const optionElement = optionElements[i];
    ids.push(optionElement.id);
}

alert(ids.join(','));
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. @Fenton